# How to invite a (sub)group of external testers to beta test through Testflight?

Tags: testflight

I have nine external testers listed for the Prerelease part of my new app. When I upload a new build, I would like to be able to send an invitation to only some of these testers, but clicking the 'Send invites' button under Builds automatically sends an invitation to all of them. Does anyone know a way around this? (i.e. short of deleting some external testers)

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close. My question clearly relates to 'software tools commonly used by programmers' and is 'a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development'. Testflight is an integral part of the iOS development environment. The link regarding 'not your customer support' is inherently problematic since the boundaries of 'customer support' are vague. If I'm struggling with one of Apple's frameworks - say, Scene Kit - should I not come to SO? Finally, the fact that combinatorial received 8 up votes indicates that SO members have found the question valuable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to Prerelease>External Testers you can click the + next to Testers and choose to "Add Existing Testers" this allows you to choose specific people to invite to test the build.

Comment: Thanks. I incorrectly thought the '+' button was for managing testers in general, and not for this specific build. Managing testers in general is actually done in Users and Roles. I've marked yours as a correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, can't repro. Any changes as far as you know?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If i click + i see the list of all my testers grayed out, no way to select/unselect them. Am i missing something?

Comment: You can't remove them, you can only add them. If they all have checks next to them and are all greyed out then they are all already added.

Comment: @RonH Of note: if you click "Edit" and remove a user, you're just removing them from that specific app, not removing them as External testers in general, which was a bit confusing to me at first. Also this answer wasn't actually marked as "accepted". :)

Answer (score 0):

New update on iTunes Connect (TestFlight) you can have multiple groups on the external section and release different versions to each group.

[What's New in TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04112017a)

Answer (score -5):

No way, sorry.

Testflight was **shut down** at the end of February. From your [friendly tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/testflight/info) (how did you miss that?):

> TestFlight was a developer tool provided by Apple for distributing iOS builds to beta testers. The service was terminated on February 26, 2015, and the functionality is now provided by iTunes Connect.

Comment: Actually, TestFlight was not 'shut down'. It was purchased by Apple and subsequently incorporated into iTunes Connect. It is still called TestFlight, as you can see in this link:

https://developer.apple.com/testflight/update/

The question I asked refers to this new implementation of TestFlight.